# Optimization of a Java code

Tags: java, optimization

This is a code in an online contest I've been trying. The time limit set at the online judge is 1 sec and the order of test cases is 10^5.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class My_Number {
    int primeNo;
    boolean divisible[] = new boolean [60];

    My_Number(int primeNo) {
        this.primeNo = primeNo;
    }

    void setDivisible() {
        for (int i=0; i<60; i++) {
            if(i%primeNo == 0) {
                divisible[i] = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
class BestWorse {
    My_Number gb [] = {
        new My_Number(2), new My_Number(3), new My_Number(5), new My_Number(7), new My_Number(11),
        new My_Number(13), new My_Number(17), new My_Number(19), new My_Number(23), new My_Number(29), 
        new My_Number(31), new My_Number(37), new My_Number(41), new My_Number(43), new My_Number(47), 
        new My_Number(53), new My_Number(59)
    };

    boolean master_list [] = new boolean [86400];
    void initialize() {
        for (My_Number gb1 : gb) {
            gb1.setDivisible();
        }
    }

    private boolean isBad(int hh, int mm, int ss) {
        for(My_Number gb1: gb) {
            if(gb1.divisible[hh] && gb1.divisible[mm] && gb1.divisible[ss]) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
        private int findGCD(int a, int b) {
           int r, i;
            while(b!=0){
              r = a % b;
              a = b;
              b = r;
            }
            return a;
        }
        void fillUpTheMasterList() {
            int hh =0, mm = 0, ss = 1;
            while( !(hh==0 && ss==0 && mm==0)) {
                if (isBad(hh, mm, ss)) {
                    master_list[hh*60*60+mm*60+ss] = true;

                }
                ss++;
                if(ss == 60) {
                    ss = 0;
                    mm++;
                    if(mm == 60) {
                        mm = 0;
                        hh++;
                        if(hh == 24) {
                            hh = 0;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    String countBestAndWorse(int hh, int mm, int ss) {
        int good = 0, bad = 0;
        for(int i=hh*60*60+mm*60+ss; i<86400; i++) {
            if(master_list[i]) {
                bad++;
            }
            else {
                good++;
            }
        }

        if(good != 0 && bad != 0)
        {
            int gcd = findGCD(good, bad);
            good /= gcd;
            bad /= gcd;
        }
        return bad + ":" +good;
    }

    public static void main(String[]args) {
        int n;
        Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
        BestWorse best_worse = new BestWorse();
        best_worse.initialize();
        best_worse.fillUpTheMasterList();
        n = scn.nextInt();

        for(int i=0; i<n;i++) {
            int hh = scn.nextInt();
            int mm = scn.nextInt();
            int ss = scn.nextInt();

            System.out.println(best_worse.countBestAndWorse(hh, mm, ss));
        }
    }
}
```

For some reason, I am continuously getting the error as 'Time limit exceeded'. 
Things I tried:

- Using BufferedReader instead of Scanner
- Maintaining a master_list of the answer(already implemented in my solution).

I tried the Netbeans profiler and it's output for input of 5000 (hh=0 mm=0 ss=1) numbers is pasted [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZQ4Ys.jpg). Also, the question is posted [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FTId4.png).

From the profiler, it seems like findGCD is taking up majority of the time. But I googled around and found out that this is indeed the fastest algorithm to calculate GCD. I also tried to maintain a lookup table for GCD; perhaps the same GCD is calculated again and again. Still no luck!

I've reached my limit for this question and need help. Can anyone please help me out here?

Comment: Use a profiler to find code that's taking the longest and work in that. There us too much code to make thus question useful. If you find a small code block that's slow, just post that to narrow the scope.

Comment: @Bohemian I've already done that. Please look into the image of the profiler output posted. I can't post the image on stackoverflow so I've posted it on imgur.

Comment: Please post a summary of the findings here (so ppl don't have to open an image), and post just the GCD code and the code where it's being called from. Maybe the GCD code is fine, but you're unnecessarily calling it more often then needed. People aren't going to trawl through code dumps - there's just too much code here. Narrow the code and the problem definition severely - ie remove the preamble and "cut to the chase". I have reopened this on the expectation you'll follow through

Comment: Every MyNumber object contains a `boolean[60]` array when a simple `long` would suffice.  And it sure seems like you should be able to avoid doing `setDivisible` in such an incredibly inefficient way.

Comment: @HotLicks The divisibility array inside every My_Number object is for telling the divisibility of the numbers 1 to 59 by the it's primtNumber member. Say for example we have My_Number(19). Now, the divisibility array will have 19th, 38th etc.. position as true, and the rest of them as false. I can't figure how a long can do the same job. Can you please explain how a long would suffice?

Comment: A `long` has 64 bits.  Your array has only 60.  I don't see a problem.

Comment: @HotLicks Okay. But that will contribute to space complexity; right? The online judge doesn't have problems with that. I'm getting time limit exceeded. And moreover, the won't the logic still be the same? Please correct me if I've misunderstood.

Comment: @Bohemian: As much as I want (and need) to give the required information, I don't know where exactly the problem lies. Hence, I posted my entire solution. I'll try to make the code clearer. Please bear with me.

Comment: @HotLicks: 'you should be able to avoid doing setDivisible in such an incredibly inefficient way'. Can you please suggest an alternative?

Comment: It costs time to allocate those arrays.  Half your object allocation time is spent in those arrays.  Plus indexing the arrays is less efficient than using a `long` with bitmasks.

Comment: I can not make sense of this question. Next time, try providing the complete requirements for a solution (your screenshot looks incomplete as it does not specify which seconds are "bad for Chandran"), isolating the code that is slow (you claim GCD is a bottle neck even though it is called exactly once?), and posting it with correct formatting (your indentation is messed up).

Answer (score 0):

Its all about using the correct algorithm.

Check out this approach:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GoodBadTime
{
    private int goodTimeCounter[][][];
    private int badTimeCounter[][][];

    private static final int primes[] = { 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23 };

    public GoodBadTime ()
    {
        initializeGoodBadTimes ();

        try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner (System.in))
        {
            int testCases = scanner.nextInt ();

            for (int i = 0; i < testCases; ++i)
            {
                int h = scanner.nextInt ();
                int m = scanner.nextInt ();
                int s = scanner.nextInt ();

                System.out.println (badTimeCounter[h][m][s] + ":" + goodTimeCounter[h][m][s]);
            }
        }
    }

    private void initializeGoodBadTimes ()
    {
        goodTimeCounter = new int[24][60][60];
        badTimeCounter = new int[24][60][60];

        int cumulativeGoodCounter = 0;
        int cumulativeBadCounter = 0;

        for (int h = 23; h >= 0; --h)
        {
            for (int m = 59; m >= 0; --m)
            {
                for (int s = 59; s >= 0; --s)
                {
                    boolean isBadTime = false;
                    int prime;
                    for (int p = 0; p < primes.length && ((prime = primes[p]) <= h); ++p)
                    {
                        if (h % prime == 0 && m % prime == 0 && s % prime == 0)
                        {
                            isBadTime = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    if (isBadTime)
                    {
                        ++cumulativeBadCounter;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ++cumulativeGoodCounter;
                    }

                    int gcd = GCD (cumulativeGoodCounter, cumulativeBadCounter);
                    goodTimeCounter[h][m][s] = cumulativeGoodCounter / gcd;
                    badTimeCounter[h][m][s] = cumulativeBadCounter / gcd;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private int GCD (int p, int q)
    {
        if (p == 0 || q == 0)
        {
            return 1;
        }

        while (q != 0)
        {
            int temp = q;
            q = p % q;
            p = temp;
        }

        return p;
    }

    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        new GoodBadTime ();
    }
}
```

Let me know if there's something I need to explain in my code that isn't obvious, so that I can edit my answer and explain it to you.

This was just my first attempt to solve it, there can be better ways to do it as well.
But this approach should give out the output within 1 second, so I guess, I don't cross the threshold limit with this approach.

**Update**
Here's an update to the answer:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class GoodBadTime
{
    private int goodTimeCounter[];
    private int badTimeCounter[];

    private static final int primes[] = { 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23 };

    public GoodBadTime ()
    {
        initializeGoodBadTimes ();

        try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (System.in)))
        {
            int testCases = Integer.parseInt (reader.readLine ());

            for (int i = testCases; i > 0; --i)
            {
                String[] hms = reader.readLine ().split ("\\s+");

                int h = Integer.parseInt (hms[0]);
                int m = Integer.parseInt (hms[1]);
                int s = Integer.parseInt (hms[2]);

                int index = h + 24 * (m + 60 * s);
                System.out.printf ("%d:%d\n", badTimeCounter[index], goodTimeCounter[index]);
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace ();
        }
    }

    private void initializeGoodBadTimes ()
    {
        goodTimeCounter = new int[24 * 60 * 60];
        badTimeCounter = new int[24 * 60 * 60];

        int cumulativeGoodCounter = 0;
        int cumulativeBadCounter = 0;

        for (int h = 23; h >= 0; --h)
        {
            for (int m = 59; m >= 0; --m)
            {
                for (int s = 59; s >= 0; --s)
                {
                    boolean isBadTime = false;
                    int prime;
                    for (int p = 0; p < primes.length && ((prime = primes[p]) <= h); ++p)
                    {
                        if (h % prime == 0 && m % prime == 0 && s % prime == 0)
                        {
                            isBadTime = true;
                            ++cumulativeBadCounter;
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    if (!isBadTime)
                    {
                        ++cumulativeGoodCounter;
                    }

                    int gcd = GCD (cumulativeGoodCounter, cumulativeBadCounter);

                    // Original[h, m, s] = Flat[h + 24 * (m + 60 * s)]
                    int index = h + 24 * (m + 60 * s);
                    goodTimeCounter[index] = cumulativeGoodCounter / gcd;
                    badTimeCounter[index] = cumulativeBadCounter / gcd;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private int GCD (int p, int q)
    {
        if (p == 0 || q == 0)
        {
            return 1;
        }

        while (q != 0)
        {
            int temp = q;
            q = p % q;
            p = temp;
        }

        return p;
    }

    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        new GoodBadTime ();
    }
}
```

This should be faster than the previous one, since I'm using 1D array and `BufferedReader` this time.

Here's a **C** equivalent:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int goodTimeCounter[24 * 60 * 60];
int badTimeCounter[24 * 60 * 60];

const int primes[] = { 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23 };

int GCD (int p, int q)
{
    if (p == 0 || q == 0)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    while (q != 0)
    {
        int temp = q;
        q = p % q;
        p = temp;
    }

    return p;
}

void initializeGoodBadTimes ()
{
    int cumulativeGoodCounter = 0;
    int cumulativeBadCounter = 0;

    for (int h = 23; h >= 0; --h)
    {
        for (int m = 59; m >= 0; --m)
        {
            for (int s = 59; s >= 0; --s)
            {
                int isBadTime = 0;
                int prime;
                for (int p = 0; p < 9 && ((prime = primes[p]) <= h); ++p)
                {
                    if (h % prime == 0 && m % prime == 0 && s % prime == 0)
                    {
                        isBadTime = 1;
                        ++cumulativeBadCounter;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (!isBadTime)
                {
                    ++cumulativeGoodCounter;
                }

                int gcd = GCD (cumulativeGoodCounter, cumulativeBadCounter);

                // Original[h, m, s] = Flat[h + 24 * (m + 60 * s)]
                int index = h + 24 * (m + 60 * s);
                goodTimeCounter[index] = cumulativeGoodCounter / gcd;
                badTimeCounter[index] = cumulativeBadCounter / gcd;
            }
        }
    }
}

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    initializeGoodBadTimes();

    int testCases;
    scanf("%d", &testCases);

    for(int i = testCases; i > 0; --i)
    {
        int h, m, s;
        scanf("%d %d %d", &h, &m, &s);

        int index = h + 24 * (m + 60 * s);
        printf("%d:%d\n", badTimeCounter[index], goodTimeCounter[index]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Note: GCD is calculated constant number of times, irrespective of the input size.
Also, `int` is sufficient for this program, since no counter ever exceeds 86400 since that's the maximum number of good or bad times that can happen.

Its equally strange for me that Online Judge is calling it as "Wrong Answer", since I think I am following every constraint set by the question.

Also, while testing for the two inputs, the program gave the correct answer despite the input being far apart in time. Induction would say that it should keep giving correct answers. Do you happen to know which output is wrong?

Also, can you put a link to this question which is present on the Online Judge site, so that I can check it out myself, and provide a correct answer to you?

Comment: Sorry to say, the online judge still says [this](http://i.imgur.com/U1EHm6j.png).

Comment: So now its taking 1.4 seconds. And I need to bring it down to 1 second. Is that what it means? There are optimisations that I can come up with even on this algorithm. Though I didn't expect I would have to. Haha.

Comment: I see you're going backwards in time to store up the cumulative good and bad times. I like it. It's a shame I can't upvote your answer!

Comment: Ah thanks. :) Do you think making this multithreaded will help? Do you have any opinions regarding improving this algorithm? Or any number crunching that can save us some time?

Comment: Not really. I don't have concrete ideas to optimize it. I'll try though. But I'm now a bit skeptical of the online judge. I tried to submit the code 3 times. The time limit exceeds were 1.5, 1.4 1.6 seconds. Also, they have same time limit for C and Java code. It's insane.

Comment: I don't do competitive programming, but looks like I should start doing it. :D I've updated the answer with little optimisation. Let me know if this works. Or I'll try optimising it more. If this were written in C, I'm sure it would have passed.

Comment: 1.4999. Time limit exceeded :|

Comment: The algorithmic complexity of this approach is linear. I'm aware that I'm doing some calculations that can be optimised, but its already late for my head to think properly. If I were you, I would have written it in C, and posted it for checking. Maybe I'll give this one a shot later. Till the mean time, try coming up with improved solutions. Its all about the approach you use.

Comment: I'm doing exactly that. Converting it to C.

Comment: There are some SIGFPE errors for C code coming on the online judge. I'll rectify it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I did some benchmarking, and apparently `initializeGoodBadTimes` method is just taking about 18 milliseconds on average to run. So the issue is in the way I'm taking the input since the output is just printing out the pre-calculated values. If there are 10^5 inputs and just 1 second to process, 103+ lines need to be processed each millisecond, if the time limit is to be kept under threshold. `Scanner` is the culprit. :P Try porting it to C, and it should work, since its `printf` and `scanf` are really fast.

Comment: I converted it to C++ code pasted [here](http://pastebin.com/D4XFHak0).  Time limit doesn't exceed; but it says 'Wrong answer'.

Comment: @AmanAgnihotri Agreed, there's nothing as slow as `Scanner`. But this is no reason to write some C code, a trivial IO routine should do.

Comment: @AmanAgnihotri I also tried replacing int by long in the C++ code. Still it says wrong answer.

Answer (score 0):

The contest is rather unclear; at least to me. It says "none of them was divisible by the same prime number" which makes no sense, and if it did, I'd interpret it as that all the numbers must be co-prime. The next sentence sounds more like `gcd(h, gcd(m, s)) <= 1` for good days.

I'm offering some untested potential improvements to Aman Agnihotri's algorithms. By creating the cumulative table, the biggest optimization is already done.

There is a [faster GDC algorithm](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/source/browse/guava/src/com/google/common/math/IntMath.java?r=90a75c93246f0a403fc20275cb80d60e79978933#347), but I wouldn't bother as all you need is to fill a 60x60 table. This could be done even without GCD by something like

```
int[] gcdTable = new int[60*60];
Arrays.fill(gcdTable, 1);
for (int p=2; p<60; ++p)
    for (int i=0; i<60; i+=p)
        for (int j=0; j<60; j+=p)
            gcdTable[60*i+j] = Math.max(gcdTable[60*i+j], p);
```

Then use it as

```
int gcd(int a, int b) {
    return gcdTable[60*a+b];
}
```

in

```
boolean isGood(int h, int m, int s) {
    return gcd(h, gcd(m, s)) <= 1;
}
```

to fill the cumulative table. I guess, using a 1D array via

```
int secondOfDay(int h, int m, int s) {
     return 3600*h + 60*m + s;
}
```

should be a bit faster than a 3D array. You don't need to store both remaining good and bad seconds, as their sum equals to `24*3600 - secondOfDay`. My above table is too small for use for the expressing of the B:G ratio in smallest common terms, so you'll need one proper GCD per sample.